# Android logback SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy not triggering

Tags: android, logging, logback, rollingfileappender

I'm using logback for android, and I'm configuring it in code because I want the log directory to dynamically change depending on the phone (e.g. some phones have external storage and I want to write to that, but other phones don't so we have to redirect to internal storage).

Here is my config code:

```
File logFilesDir = getLogFilesDir(this);
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
lc.reset();

RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = null;
lc.putProperty("LOG_DIR", logFilesDir.getAbsolutePath());

PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
encoder.setContext(lc);
encoder.setPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n");
encoder.start();

File logFile = new File(logFilesDir, "MyApplication.log");

FixedWindowRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
rollingPolicy.setContext(lc);
rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern("${LOG_DIR}/MyApplication.%i.log");
rollingPolicy.setMinIndex(1);
rollingPolicy.setMaxIndex(5);

SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> triggeringPolicy = new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<>();
triggeringPolicy.setContext(lc);
triggeringPolicy.setMaxFileSize("1KB"); // for testing; would otherwise be 5MB

fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<>();
fileAppender.setContext(lc);
fileAppender.setFile(logFile.getAbsolutePath());
fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
fileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
fileAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(triggeringPolicy);

rollingPolicy.setParent(fileAppender);

fileAppender.start();
rollingPolicy.start();
triggeringPolicy.start();

// add the newly created appenders to the root logger;
// qualify Logger to disambiguate from org.slf4j.Logger
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.addAppender(fileAppender);

root.info("----- Application onCreate -----");
StatusPrinter.print(lc);
```

The log writes to the correct folder and it's all working ok, except when my log file exceeds the max file size (in my testing case 1KB) it fails to roll over. Instead, the file just keeps growing.

`StatusPrinter.print` writes the following output, which looks like everything's ok

```
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [assets/logback.xml]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[null] - Active log file name: /storage/emulated/0/MyApplication/logs/MyApplication.log
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[null] - File property is set to [/storage/emulated/0/MyApplication/logs/MyApplication.log]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@34b71b53 - No compression will be used
```

I've looked at as many other similar issues as I can find, and usually people seem to miss out the RollingFileAppender or don't have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission... It doesn't seem to me like I'm hitting any of those cases. Is something about my code (vs the XML people normally use) different?

Is there anything I can do to fix this or troubleshoot it further?

Thanks

Comment: Be careful, from `android 6.0` you should always check `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)` before writing file to sdcard. If you cant write to sdcard, the error maybe comes from "Requesting Permissions at Run Time": http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Ahhh. I did have some issue writing to external storage on android 6 and I hadn't sorted that out. I'll address it. Anyway, the issue is definitely happening on android 5

Answer (score 0):

I can't immediately tell what the problem is, but it would be helpful add an `OnConsoleStatusListener` to see what happens during the rollover:

```
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
lc.reset();
OnConsoleStatusListener.addNewInstanceToContext(lc);
```

Rollover problems from `RollingFileAppender` are typically caused by a mix of absolute and relative paths in their configuration ([Issue #117](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/117), [Issue #110](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/110)) or missing the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (which is not the case for you). The debug output from `OnConsoleStatusListener` might shed some light. If not, I can try to debug it if you create a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues), preferably with an Android Studio project that reproduces the problem.